# Hide after setInterval in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to build a bar which appears after each 20 seconds and disappear after 5 seconds. It's working but often gives me error that `classname` in `document.querySelector(".The_Bar").className = "The_Bar";` doesn't exist. **So, is there any way to improvise this?**

```
const Bar = () => {


  React.useEffect(() => {   
    const BarInterval = setInterval(() => {
      document.querySelector(".The_Bar").className = "The_Bar The_Bar_Show";
      const BarTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector(".The_Bar").className = "The_Bar";
      }, 5000);
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(BarTimeout);
      };
    }, 20000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(BarInterval);
      setNumber({});
    };
  }, [])

  
  return (
    <div className="The_Bar">
      <div className="Text">You viewing this page</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are seeing? You should add that to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,Why do you use `document.querySelector(".The_Bar").className` in react?

For this you have `useRef`.

Second, if you want to dispaly and then remove a div, you can `useState` to change dynamically. this way you control the class using react hooks which more easy and "clean"

```
const Bar = () => {
const [showBar,setShowBar] = useState(false)

  React.useEffect(() => {   
    const BarInterval = setInterval(() => {
     setShowBar(true)
      const BarTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
     setShowBar(false)
      }, 5000);
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(BarTimeout);
      };
    }, 20000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(BarInterval);
      setNumber({});
    };
  }, [])

  
  return (
   <div className={showBar ? "The_Bar The_Bar_Show" : "No_Bar"}>
      <div className="Text">You viewing this page</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

No_Bar style :

```
{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, I want the Bar to continuously appear and disappear after certain time

Comment: That what i wrote, you DON'T use document.querySelector in react. you need to manage your css with state. did you try the code that i wrote?

Comment: This is the correct one - @yanirmidler please correct and may be you can explain how it works `<div className={showBar ? "The_Bar The_Bar_Show" : "No_Bar"}>`

Comment: You need to create this state. Do you know what it is react hooks?

Comment: @yanirmidler Thank you so much!!! It's working now. And yeah I do know what hook is, your answer wasn't showing completely because I forgot to refresh the browser. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use such imperative approach to manipulate DOM when using React, try to achieve the same behaviour in a declarative way:

```
const Bar = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let interval;
    let timeout;

    interval = setInterval(() => {
      setShow(true);
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        setShow(false);
      }, 1000);
    }, 5000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    show && (
      <div className="The_Bar">
        <div className="Text">You viewing this page</div>
      </div>
    )
  );
};
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ehwj9c

Selecting DOM elements with selectors in React is never a good idea, React makes use of a Virtual DOM to paint DOM and makes it asynchronously, so you may face all soort of bugs and misbehaviours by mixing imperative vanilla code with React code. You could use `refs` to access DOM nodes, but that also should be done very carefully.
Instead of imperatively toggling a class as you would do in Vanilla JS, just toggle a React state, and use that state to declaratively toggle a view, or toggle a className, since React State triggers a re-render, this ensures that everything happens at the right pace.